# Javascript some function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently inside my javascript there are two functions which are working - `function isChecked(checkbox, sub1)` and `function change(obj)` - while the other two functions under `$(document).ready()` are not working.

There's no console error nor do I think the codes are wrong. Somehow this two functions aren't running at all.

How do I run a console log to debug further ?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Order CDs</title>
</head>
<body>

<script type = "text/javascript">

function isChecked(checkbox, sub1) {
    var button = document.getElementById(sub1);

    if (checkbox.checked === true) {
        button.disabled = "";
    } else {
        button.disabled = "disabled";
    }
}

function change(obj) {

        var selectBox = obj;
        var selected = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
        var retCustDetails = document.getElementById("retCustDetails");
        var tradeCustDetails = document.getElementById("tradeCustDetails");

        if(selected === 'ret'){
            retCustDetails.style.display = "block";
            tradeCustDetails.style.display = "none";
        }
        else{
            retCustDetails.style.display = "none";
            tradeCustDetails.style.display = "block";
        }
    }

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#termsChkbx').change(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked'))
        {
            $(this).parent('p').css('color','black');
        }
        else
        {
             $(this).parent('p').css('color','red');
        }
    });  

$(document).on("click",".chosen",function() {
        var sum=0;
    var chk=$(this).find("input");
    if(chk.is(':checked')) {
        sum = sum + parseInt(chk.val());
    } else {
        sum = sum - parseInt(chk.val());
    }
    $('#total').val(sum);
}); 

});

</script>
```

Comment: Do you have firebug or similar in the browser? The console output is the first tab.

Comment: I have Xdebug helper extension on my Chrome but not able to find the logs

Comment: You don't need an extension in chrome. Just click right in your browser window, _inspect element_ and there you'll find everything you need.

Comment: Whether using Chrome or Firefox, press `F12` to open debugger. Click on "Console" tab. Here you will get all error logs, and custom logs, if used `console.log("my own message")`. Keyboard shortcuts: `ctrl+shift+j`, `ctrl+shift+i` or `f12`

Answer (score 1):

You can run `console.log(someVariableName)` to output the value of any variable to the console. In most browsers you open the deveoper tools with F12 where you can see the output.

You will most likely also find a useful debugger there that allows you to run and observe the execution of your program step by step.

Comment: I found an error on debug which says on Line 38 referring to $(document).ready(function(){ -> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: Use `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"> </script>` to import jQuery library before first use of `$`, preferably in `head` section.

Answer (score 1):

You would use `console.log("My log message")` or `console.log(myLogVariable)`.

In your example I'd say you forgot to load JQuery. Add this to your `<head>` section.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"> </script>` to import jQuery library before first use of `$`. I've added it for you in `head` section.

```
 <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Order CDs</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"> </script>
        </head>
    <body>
```

Now your code is error free. For debugging, you can use `console.log("Anything")` or `console.log("Anything")`. This will get printed in `console` tab. 
 Press `F12` to open debugger. Click on "Console" tab. Here you will get all error logs, and custom logs, if used `console.log("my own message")`. 
Keyboard shortcuts: `ctrl+shift+j`, `ctrl+shift+i` or `f12`